# Gradient only defined for scalar-output functions. Output had shape: (1,)

Tags: python, gradient, gradient-descent

I'm working with gradients and having some troubles, here is my code

```py
import jax

def model(x):
    return (x+1)**2 + (x-1)**2

def loss(x, y):
    return y - model(x)

x = 2
grad = jax.grad(loss, argnums=0)
gradient = grad(x, 0)
```

And in the last line, I get the following error

> TypeError: Gradient only defined for scalar-output functions. Output had shape: (1,).
> The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
> The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified

How can I solve?

Comment: Should your `loss` and `loss_` be the same?

Comment: @deponovo yes they are sorry, I misclicked when copying the code

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce the problem without a minimal working example. What is `jax`?

Comment: Read shortly the docs. Should your `loss` function not be a compiled one of some sort? Like using `jit` or some `jax` API for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The `grad` function requires real or complex-valued inputs but you are using integers. This chunk will work

```
import jax

def model(x):
  return (x+1)**2 + (x-1)**2

def loss(x, y):
  return y - model(x)

x=2.0
grad = jax.grad(loss)
gradient = grad(x, 0.0)
```